# Commutator of Skew-Symmetric Matrices with Integer entries

Tags: skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $\mathcal{S_3}$ be the collection of $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrices with integer entries. There is no non-zero $D\in \mathcal{S_3}$ that satisfies the following equation
$$[D,[D,[D,N]]]=0$$
for all $N\in \mathcal{S_3}$ where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the usual commutator of matrices ($[A,B]=AB-BA$).

How can I prove or disprove this for all $n$, i.e., show or disprove that there is no $D\in \mathcal{S_n}\setminus {0}$ such that $[D,[D,[D,N]]]=0$ for any $N\in \mathcal{S_n}$?

I've attempted to prove it by considering the generators of $\mathcal{S_n}$ and then computing its commutator with one another. I then expressed $D$ as the linear combination of those generators. It is very tedious (even if I let $N$ to be one of the generators) and I did not get any result. I am now looking for other ways to prove or disprove it. Does $\mathcal{S_n}$ have properties you that might be useful in this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The equality implies $ad(D)^3=0$ in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$. So the linear operator $ad(D)$, defined by $ad(D)(N)=[D,N]=DN-ND$, consisting of a skew-symmetric matrix, is nilpotent. It follows that $ad(D)=0$, because the only skew-symmetric nilpotent matrix is the zero matrix. It follows that $D=0$, a contradiction.